# Como mudar o "src" de um iframe sem alterar a URL do usuário?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Como trocar o conteúdo de um iframe internamente sem alterar a URL do site?

Exemplo: O usuário entrou no meu site: `http://example.com` e nele contem um  iframe:

```
<iframe src="http://teste455.esy.es/v3/wp-content/arcade/?url=Rockman X 3 (J).smc&amp;system=snes&amp;plataforma=snes" width="640" height="500" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Nesse iframe tem um link. Como faço para ao invés de usar vários iframes em uma página, eu possa ir mudando o conteudo do iframe, no caso o link, apenas com um menu suspenso que ao ser clicado o conteudo do iframe seja alterado?

Seria igual uma playlist e teria um menu suspenso acima do iframe e ao clicar o link do iframe seria alterado para outro que no caso é igual essa que está ai em cima.

Gostaria de fazer isso em uma única pagina HTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conforme [esta excelente resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23228820/1287812), o `iframe` é simplesmente um parente do antigo `frame`, então é só uma questão de definir o `target` no seu elemento do menu (provavelmente um `<a>`):

```html
<iframe width="500" height="500" src="about:blank" name="testframe"></iframe>

<a href="http://example.com/pagina-1" target="testframe">Um</a>
<a href="http://example.com/pagina-2" target="testframe">Dois</a>
```

Comment: Então mas como que se faz para essa parte dos links aparecer em menu suspenso?

Comment: @Endou, o esquema do Stack é basicamente assim: você faz *uma* pergunta de cada vez. Você não perguntou sobre menu suspenso, perguntou sobre iframe. . . . . . Lembrando que: não tem problema nenhum em perguntar aqui até completar um projeto inteiro, mas **é essencial** que você vá batendo cabeça e faça suas perguntas **só depois** de testar bastante e não achar resposta.

Comment: Eu achei a solução aqui mesmo no site. só que como sempre assim que encontro uma solução aparece outra duvida/problema.

Comment: Pois é, programação é um bicho de 7 cabeças. O Stack é site de 1 pergunta ;)

Comment: No dia que pra você programação seja um bicho de 4 cabeças, pode ter certeza que ficou bom no troço, jejeje