# Quero chamar 3 ou mais links diferentes dentro do mesmo iframe, em acordo com um ID, ou algo assim, que eu possa fazer em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, iframe

Esse é o `iframe` que chama um *link*, queria manter essa estrutura de `iframe` e que possa chamar mais `iframes` mantendo essa estrutura:

```
<div>
        <iframe      
                width="1100"
                height="500"
                id="teste"
                src="google.com"
                scrolling="no">
        </iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Queres mostrar links diferentes dentro do mesmo iFrame? é isso? e como sabes que deve mudar a página dentro do iFrame, há algum sitio onde o utilizador deve clicar?

Comment: Olhe -> http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/92199/como-mudar-o-src-de-um-iframe-sem-alterar-a-url-do-usu%C3%A1rio?rq=1

Comment: preciso de chamar os links diferentes pelo java script, em acordo com algum parâmetro